# Как передать в ссылке GET-параметр

Tags: php

Как передать метод get в ссылку? Например первая ссылка должна выглядеть вот так "/index.php?from=primirskoe";

```
<a href="index.php" name="primirskoe">Еду с Прымирського</a><br>
<a href="index.php" name="bogdana">Еду с Богдана</a>
```

Comment: `href="index.php?from=value"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="index.php?from=primirskoe" name="primirskoe">Еду с Прымирського</a><br>
<a href="index.php?from=bogdana" name="bogdana">Еду с Богдана</a>
```

Ответ на ваш вопрос. Надеюсь это то что вы хотели (исходя из самого вопроса)